# flutter CupertinoTabscaffold how to add customized button at bottombar?

Tags: flutter

It looks like in Cupertino style we must using CupertinoTabScaffold for tabbed navigation. Now I want add a customized button in the middle of bar, any way to do it?

I only saw a

tabBuilder

func in CupertinotabScaffold, which returns a Page for every single tab, but I want some of it pop up a window, how to do it?

[image]

wanna something like this,

but I need the button inside tabbar

Comment: can you include your ui too?

Comment: Add code snippet for better understanding of your problem